# Can't update using GridView

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I can't seem to update the database after selecting one of the listitem in my dropdownlist control. Does anybody have an idea why?

I got this error message:

**'ddl' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.Parameter name: value**

Here is the markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="OrdersDataSource" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="gridview" DataKeyNames="OrderId">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="Status" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderId" HeaderText="OrderId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="OrderId" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="OrdersDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Status], [OrderId] FROM [Order]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Order] SET [Status] = @Status WHERE [OrderId] = @OrderId">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrderId" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values for the Status drop down list are "1" and "2". One or more of the statuses you're trying to bind to it is something other than "1" or "2". You must change it so that any status you attempt to bind it to is represented in the list of possible values.

Look at the results of the query, at the status column, to determine what the values are and add them as possible values.